# \floatsep does not get reflected

Tags: floats

The thesis I am writing uses this .sty template, and there are lines to set \textfloatsep, \floatsep, and \intextsep, but no matter how large I make them they do not seem to affect the spacing between figures A and B when they are positioned next to each other. The spacing between the figures and the texts can be changed successfully, but when the figures end up next to each other like in this example, the latex does not respect the spacing set by \floatsep. In the example here the spacing is set to 175pt to over-exaggerate, but it does not get reflected on the document. I could force spacings between figures by applying vspace, but that potentially introduces new issues for figures elsewhere. Is there a way to enforce a strict minimum spacing between figures and texts throughout the documents so I don't have to check each figure one by one and measure the spacing?

thesistemplate.sty file:

```
\setlength{\voffset}{-0.5in}
\marginparwidth 40pt \marginparsep 10pt
\topmargin 0in \headsep .31in
\textheight 8.94in \textwidth 6.5in
\brokenpenalty=10000

\RequirePackage{afterpage} %needed for manual Page Head fix
\RequirePackage{atbegshi}

\oddsidemargin 0.00in
\if@twoside
  \evensidemargin 0.0in
\else
  \evensidemargin 0.0in
\fi

\textfloatsep  175pt plus 2pt minus 4pt
\floatsep 175pt plus 2pt minus 4pt
\intextsep  175pt plus 2pt minus 4pt %%%% added FRW

\def\textfraction{.25}
\def\floatpagefraction{.5}

\def\cl@chapter{\@elt{section}\@elt{footnote}}
\def\thefigure{\@arabic\c@figure}
\def\thetable{\@arabic\c@table}
\def\thechapter{\@arabic\c@chapter}
\def\theequation{\arabic{equation}}
\renewcommand{\figurename}{FIG.}
\renewcommand{\tablename}{TABLE}
\renewcommand{\bibname}{BIBLIOGRAPHY}
\renewcommand{\chaptername}{CHAPTER}
\renewcommand{\appendixname}{APPENDIX}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}

\renewcommand\@dotsep{0.4}

\renewcommand{\@pnumwidth}{0pt{}}
%\renewcommand{\@}{2em}
\renewcommand{\large}{\fontsize{12.0}{\baselineskip}}
\renewcommand{\dotfill}{%
  \leavevmode\cleaders\hbox to 0.3em{\hss .\hss }\hfill\kern0pt }

\newcommand{\tocShipoutHook}{\noindent{Chapter}~\hfill{Page}\par\vspace{0pt}}
\newcommand{\lofShipoutHook}{\noindent{Figure}~\hfill{Page}\par\vspace{0pt}}
\newcommand{\lotShipoutHook}{\noindent{Table}~\hfill{Page}\par\vspace{0pt}}
\newcommand{\MyShipoutHook}{}

\long\def\@caption#1[#2]#3{%
  \par
  \addcontentsline{\csname ext@#1\endcsname}{#1}%
   {\csname the#1\endcsname.  {\ignorespaces #2}}%
  \begingroup
   \@parboxrestore
   \if@minipage
   \@setminipage
   \fi
   \normalsize
   \@makecaption{\csname fnum@#1\endcsname}{\ignorespaces #3}\par
  \endgroup}

\def\dept#1{\gdef\@dept{#1}}
\def\principaladviser#1{\gdef\@principaladviser{#1}}
\def\submitdate#1{\gdef\@submitdate{#1}}
\def\copyrightyear#1{\gdef\@copyrightyear{#1}} % \author, \title in report
\def\degrees#1{\gdef\@degrees{#1}}
\def\abstract#1{\def\@abstract{#1}}
\def\@title{}\def\@author{}\def\@dept{computer science}
\def\@principaladviser{}
\def\@degrees{}
\def\@abstract{}
\def\vita#1{\gdef\@vita{#1}}
\def\@vita{}

\def\@submitdate{\ifcase\the\month\or
  January\or February\or March\or April\or May\or June\or
  July\or August\or September\or October\or November\or December\fi
  \space \number\the\year}
\ifnum\month=12
    \@tempcnta=\year \advance\@tempcnta by 1
    \edef\@copyrightyear{\number\the\@tempcnta}
\else
    \def\@copyrightyear{\number\the\year}
\fi
\newif\ifcopyright \newif\iffigurespage \newif\iftablespage
\copyrighttrue \figurespagetrue \tablespagetrue

\newif\ifphd
\phdtrue




\def\signline#1{\\
                 {\small #1} \\}


\def\@member{}
\def\member#1{\expandafter\def\expandafter\@member\expandafter
{\@member{\signline{#1\ (Member)}}}}

\def\titlep{%
        \def\baselinestretch{2.0}\@normalsize
        \thispagestyle{empty}%
        \begin{center}
                {\large\bf\uppercase\expandafter{\@title}}
        \end{center}
        \renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.0}\@normalsize
        \begin{center}
                 by\\
                 \ \\
                %\vspace{15pt}
                \@author\\
                \@degrees\\
        \end{center}
        %\vfill
        \vspace{15pt}
        \begin{center}
                A \ifphd Dissertation \else Thesis \fi Submitted to the Faculty of\\
                B University in Partial Fulfillment of the\\
                Requirements for the Degree of\\
                %\vspace{18pt}
                \ \\
                \ifphd \uppercase{Doctor of Philosophy} \else \uppercase{Master of Science}\fi \\
                %\vspace{18pt}
                \ \\
                \uppercase\expandafter{\@dept}\\
                %\vspace{18pt}
                \ \\
                \uppercase{B University}\\
                \@submitdate\\
        \end{center}
        \vfill
        \hfill\parbox[t]{2.5in}{Approved by:\\
                                \signline{\@principaladviser\ (Director)}
                                \@member}
        \vfill\newpage}


\def\abstractpage{\def\baselinestretch{1.3}\@normalsize\pagestyle{empty}%
        \begin{center}
                {\large\bf ABSTRACT}\\
                %\vspace{18pt}
                \ \\
                \renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.0}\@normalsize
                {\large\uppercase\expandafter{\@title}}\\
                \vspace{18pt}
                \@author\\
                B University, \number\the\year\\
                Director: Dr. \@principaladviser 
        \end{center}
        \vspace{25pt}
        \par
        \@abstract
        \vfill\newpage}

\def\vitapage{\def\baselinestretch{1.3}\@normalsize\pagestyle{myheadings}
              \chapter*{VITA}
              \addtocontents{toc}{\vspace*{12pt}}
              \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{VITA}
              \begin{flushleft}
                 \@author\\
                 Department of \@dept \\
                 B University \\
                 C City, D State ZipCode
              \end{flushleft}
              \par
              \@vita
              \vfill
              \begin{flushleft}
                 Typeset using \LaTeX .
              \end{flushleft}}


\def\copyrightpage{%
        \pagestyle{myheadings}
      %  \vspace*{2in}
      \vspace*{\fill}
        \begin{center}
                Copyright,\ \@copyrightyear,\ by
                \@author,\
                All Rights Reserved.
        \end{center}
        \vfill\newpage}


\def\beforepreface{
        \pagenumbering{roman}
        \pagestyle{empty}
        \newpage
      %  \titlep
      %\cleardoublepage
      %  \abstractpage
      %\cleardoublepage
     %   \ifcopyright\copyrightpage\fi }
    }

\def\prefacesection#1{%
      \pagestyle{myheadings}
      \cleardoublepage
        \def\baselinestretch{1.3}\@normalsize
        \chapter*{#1}}

\def\afterpreface{\cleardoublepage
        \def\baselinestretch{1}\@normalsize
        \renewcommand{\MyShipoutHook}{\tocShipoutHook}
        \AtBeginShipout{\MyShipoutHook}
      %  \tableofcontents
        \renewcommand{\MyShipoutHook}{}
        \def\baselinestretch{1.3}\@normalsize
        \pagenumbering{arabic}
        \pagestyle{myheadings}
        }

\def\tableofcontents{\pagestyle{myheadings}\chapter*{Table of Contents}
 \@starttoc{toc}
 \addtocontents{toc}{\hfill Page\par}

 }
 
\def\listoffigures{\chapter*{List of Figures}

 {\setlength{\parskip}{12\p@} \@starttoc{lof}}%
 \addtocontents{lof}{\noindent Figure\hfill Page\par}

}

\renewcommand*\l@figure{\@dottedtocline{1}{0em}{0em}}

\renewcommand*\l@table{\@dottedtocline{1}{0em}{0em}}

\def\listoftables{\chapter*{List of Tables}
 {\setlength{\parskip}{12\p@} \@starttoc{lot}}%
 \addtocontents{lot}{\noindent Table\hfill Page\par}

}


\pagestyle{myheadings}
\markboth{}{}
%
% FRW added custom footnote without number for document style phrase
%
\def\nnfootnote{%
     \@ifnextchar [\@xfootnotenext
       {\protected@xdef%
%       \@thefnmark{\thempfn}%   removed the number from FOOTNOTETEXT command:
        \@thefnmark{ }%
    \@footnotetext}}
%
\renewcommand{\chapter}{\if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi
                   \thispagestyle{myheadings}%
                    \global\@topnum\z@
                    \@afterindentfalse
                    \secdef\@chapter\@schapter}
\def\@chapter[#1]#2{\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
                         \refstepcounter{chapter}%
                         \typeout{\@chapapp\space\thechapter}%
                         \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}%
                                   {\protect\numberline{\thechapter.}\uppercase{#1}}%
                    \else
                      \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\uppercase{#1}}%
                    \fi

                    \if@twocolumn
                      \@topnewpage[\@makechapterhead{#2}]%
                    \else
                      \@makechapterhead{#2}%
                      \@afterheading
                    \fi}
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
%  \vspace*{50\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
    \renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{2}
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
%        \centerline{\large\bfseries \@chapapp\space \thechapter}
        \begin{center}
        \large\bfseries \@chapapp\space \thechapter
        \end{center}
        \par\nobreak
        \vskip 12\p@
    \fi
    \interlinepenalty\@M
 %    \centerline{\large \bfseries \uppercase{#1}}\par\nobreak
    \begin{center}
    \large \bfseries \uppercase{#1}
    \end{center}
    \vskip 18\p@
  }}
\def\@schapter#1{\if@twocolumn
                   \@topnewpage[\@makeschapterhead{#1}]%
                 \else
                   \@makeschapterhead{#1}%
                   \@afterheading
                 \fi}
\def\@makeschapterhead#1{%
  %\vspace*{50\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright
    \normalfont
    \interlinepenalty\@M
 %   \centerline{
     \begin{center}
     \large \bfseries  \uppercase{#1}
     \end{center}
     \par\nobreak
   \vskip 18\p@
  }}

\renewcommand{\section}{
                    \secdef\@section\@ssection}
\def\@section[#1]#2{\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
                         \refstepcounter{section}%
                         \addcontentsline{toc}{section}%
                                   {\protect\quad\numberline{\thesection}\uppercase{#1}}%
                    \else
                      \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\uppercase{#1}}%
                    \fi
                       \@makesectionhead{#2}%
                     }
\def\@makesectionhead#1{%
        \vskip 12\p@
         {\bfseries \noindent \thesection\space\parbox[t]{5.5in}{\raggedright\uppercase{#1}}}
        \vskip 12\p@
  }
\def\@ssection#1{
                   \@makessectionhead{#1}%
                 }
\def\@makessectionhead#1{%
        \vskip 12\p@
     {\bfseries \noindent \raggedright\uppercase{#1}}
   \vskip 12\p@
  }

\renewcommand{\subsection}{
                    \secdef\@subsection\@ssubsection}
\def\@subsection[#1]#2{\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
                         \refstepcounter{subsection}%
                         \addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}%
                                   {\protect\numberline{\thesubsection}\uppercase{#1}}%
                     \fi
                    %\chaptermark{#1}%
                    %\addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
                    %\addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
                       \@makesubsectionhead{#2}%
                     }
\def\@makesubsectionhead#1{%
        \vskip 12\p@
        {\bfseries \noindent \raggedright\thesubsection\space\uppercase{#1}}
        \vskip 12\p@
  }
\def\@ssection#1{
                   \@makessubsectionhead{#1}%
                 }
\def\@makessubsectionhead#1{%
        \vskip 12\p@
     {\bfseries \noindent \raggedright\uppercase{#1}}
   \vskip 12\p@
  }
```

Main document Main.tex:

```
\tolerance=10000
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{thesistemplate}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\title{Title of the Thesis}
\author{John Smith}

 \beforepreface

 \afterpreface
   
\chapter[This is a long title This is a long title \\This is a long title This is a long title]{This is a long title This is a long title This is a long title This is a long title}
\lipsum[3-5]
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=4.5in]{example-image-a}
    \caption{This is a long caption This is a long caption This is a long caption This is a long caption}
    \label{fig:my_labels}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=4.5in]{example-image-b}
    \caption{This is a long caption This is a long caption This is a long caption This is a long caption}
    \label{fig:my_labels}
\end{figure}
\section{This is a long title This is a long title This is a long title This is a long title}
\lipsum[3-5]
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=4.5in]{example-image-c}
    \caption{This is a long caption This is a long caption This is a long caption This is a long caption}
    \label{fig:my_label}
\end{figure}

\addtocontents{toc}{\vspace*{12pt}}
\end{document}
```

Results:
[image]

Comment: Thank you for posting a working example! At the same time, much of your code does not seem to be relevant to the question you're asking here. Please limit the example to only the code required for your issue to appear. You can have a look at [this guide for how to prune your code](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3225) for this purpose.

Comment: float pages use `\@fpsep`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a float page so you want to set `\@fpsep`

eg

`\@fpsep=\floatsep`

But 175.0pt plus 2.0pt minus 4.0pt is rather large

Comment: Thank you! That is exactly what I needed. I deliberately set it to large points so that it was easier for me to see whether it was working or not.